# Geocoding Addresses to Geoids

Tags: python, pandas, api, geocoding, qgis

I am trying to create a code that takes my file containing addresses and geocodes them using the census geocoder to produce geoids.

Following a youtube tutorial, this is my code so far:

`import requests`

`import pandas as pd`

`import io`

`import csv`

``` url = '``https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/geographies/addressbatch``' ```

`files = {'addressFile': ('/Users/sofiachoudhri/Downloads/batchhh.csv',`

`open('/Users/sofiachoudhri/Downloads/batchhh.csv', 'rb'), 'text/csv')}`

`payload = {'returntype':'geographies','searchtype':'address','benchmark':'Public_AR_Current','vintage':'Current_ACS2022'}`

`s = requests.post(url, files=files, data=payload)`
`df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.text), sep=',', header=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)`

`with pd.option_context(`

`'display.width', None,`

`'display.max_columns', None,`

`'display.max_colwidth', -1,`

`'display.colheader_justify', 'left'):`

`print(df)`

Here is the error code I recieved:
``0                                                 
0

While attempting to geocode your batch input

1                                                                                                                       
0   an error occurred validating and processing the parameters that were provided.

Please validate the benchmark

2                                                           
0   vintage (if this is a geographies batch geocode request)

3
0   and addressFile parameter values that are being used and retry your batch geocode request.

More information and documentation (available in HTML and PDF formats) about the Census Geocoder and how to use it can be found here: https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/

What do I do to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Your question contains too many formatting errors for anyone to reliably guess what's going on. Please read this help article and then edit your question. [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)